# How do I project and merge MS SQL views into a feature class that can be published as a service?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql, enterprise-geodatabase, web-service

I have three views (or enterprise geodatabase tables) in a SQL database. They each contain partial components of a complete dataset, but have distinct coordinate systems. I want to project and combine these three views to a single feature class which will be published as a feature service on my ArcGIS Server. I could create an ArcPy script to accomplish this task, but that would require a scheduled run task using ArcGIS Pro which has been unstable in my testing so far.

Is there a better solution that would handle this on the SQL side?